# How would I check permissions in a template for a generic model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This may be a little difficult to explain so please bear with me.

I have a template page I use as the base page to view my models:

```
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--stuff-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block detail %}{% endblock %}
    <p><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:location.href='{{ model.get_edit_url }}';"/></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="confirm_delete('{{ model.get_delete_url }}');"/></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Return" onclick="javascript:location.href='{{ model.get_show_all_url }}';"/></p>
</body>
```

I want to add a permissions tag tag around the **Edit** and **Delete** buttons?

So I want to add this: `{% if perms.model.edit_model %}` but what do I have to do to make it generic? Hopefully this question is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check permission inside a template in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django)

Comment: @PauloScardine I'm trying to figure out how to check permission if the template doesn't know which specific model it's getting. I know to check if the model is known for the template.

Comment: Unlike [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), you cant call a method with arguments in Django templates, so I guess you have to write a custom template filter around [`request.user.has_perm("<app label>.<permission codename>")`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using django-guardian for this.

In the meta class of the model you can assign permissions as a tuple.

permissions = (("edit", "Can edit model"), etc)

Then you can manage editing and deleting of each object.

Then to implement checking if a user has the permission to do an action for that object you can using the template tags found here http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/guardian.templatetags.guardian_tags.html.

JD