# Checking for permission in django template not working

Tags: python, django

I want to verify user permission in template. If a user has permission he/she will be able to access the template. After writing the below code and I granted the user permission, when I view the page it will fall on the `{% else %}` statement. showing that the user don't have permission. How can I go about this?

```
#CREATED A GROUP IN DJANGO ADMIN CALLED 'Premium'

Class Paid(models.Model):
    #models here

    class Meta:
        permissions=(
             ("view_film","Can view film"),
        )
```

view

```
def eyo(request):
    return render_to_response('eyo.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
{% block content %}

  {% if perms.paid.can_view_film %}

      <form action='https://www.test.com/checkout' method='post'>
      <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Checkout' />
     </form>

   {% else %}

    <p> yo broke! </p>

  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please post your view

Comment: Please have a look into the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django

Comment: Ansh, I did that yet no success!

Comment: In your view or your custom admin view, make sure to pass request object or context, sometimes while customizing views context is not passed and perms is not well populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing perms in your template?
Are you setting perms.paid.can_view_film either explicitly in your view or via the admin interface?
Is the user a part of a group that has the perms.paid.can_view_film permission?

Are you sure the app name is 'paid'? That's supposed to be the app name, not the model name.

[Django Perms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#id8)

Comment: I've posted my view above. I granted the perm through Admin interface.  The user is part of the group "Premium" .

Comment: 'paid' is supposed to be your application name. What is your app name?

Comment: artapp is the appname . Paid is the model.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing some conditional rendering based on permissions in a Django project I'm currently working on. A small example of this is a particular icon. Basically if a user has a delete permission, they see one icon, if they don't, they see another. This is how it's done in my templete:

```
{% if perms.List.can_delete_list %}
    <li><a href="/social/a/search/" class="settings-edit"><span class="fui-search"></span></a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'dashboard_edit' %}" class="settings-edit"><span class="fui-new"></span></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

If the logged in user has `can_delete_list`, they view one thing. If not, they view something else. Does this help?

Comment: I should add that `List` is the class here.

Comment: That's what I did above. Just that the paid is not capitalized. And I changed the paid to Paid, yet it's not working.

Comment: Did you manually grant the user permission through the Django Admin? If so, shut down the server and restart it. I've had trouble with permission based views because of that before. My second suggestion would be to try using the built in Django permissions to make sure you can get it to work before using a custom permission. In my example, `can_delete_list` is an auto generated permission by Django.