# Django check user permission in template

Tags: python, django

I want to edit user permissions.

My View

```
def edit_roles(request,username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user_permissions = user.get_all_permissions()
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(Q(codename='can_create_product') | Q(codename='can_view_product')
    return render_to_response('users/edit_user_roles.html',{'permissions':permissions,'user_permissions':user_permissions},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Permission</th>
        <th>Access</th>
    </tr>
    {% for permission in permissions %}
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td>
                {{permission.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" {% if permission in user_permissions  %} checked="checked" {% endif %} />
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now I got user permissions. but `{% if permission in user_permissions  %}`not working. Please suggest me a good way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fetch user's permissions this way:

```
user_permissions = user.user_permissions.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can replace `user_permissions` by `request.user.get_all_permissions` ? (if you want to get permissions for the User sending the request).

You can get more info about [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions) in the docs.

However, according to [this previous StackOverflow anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django), there may be a more efficient way to check permissions in template.