# Check for string in queryset within a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I know this should be straight-forward, but for some reasons I'm not getting the results I want.

This instruction: `{{user.profile.role.all}}` in my Django template outputs this:

```
<QuerySet [<Role: Creator>, <Role: Performer>, <Role: Venue>]>
```

I'd like to check if a role is within this queryset; so, for instance, if I want to check if a role 'venue' is present, according to what the documentation tells me, I should do:

```
{% if "Venue" in user.profile.role.all %}
```

Right? The above-mentioned `if`, though, returns false. Why is that?

Comment: Because a string is something different than a Role with the given name?

Comment: OK, thanks. So, would that be better for me to build a list (of strings) in the view first, since I'll be doing this check a few times in the template?

Comment: probably better a set of strings, since that has *O(1)* average lookup time.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit lost. What is a 'set of strings'? If this is what I have in my view: `context['role'] = Role.objects.filter(profile__id=self.get_object().id)`, how would I do that?

Comment: can you share your `Role` model?

Comment: Very simple: `class Role(models.Model):

    type= models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type`

Comment: Linked to the user with `role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)` from the User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because a string is something different than a `Role` with as name the same string.

You can pass a set of role names to the template, for example with:

```
context['role'] = Role.objects.filter(
    profile__user=self.request.user
).values_list('type', flat=True)
```

Comment: Yes, that does it! Thanks.

Comment: Wait, but why does `{% if "Venue" or "Promoter" in roleList %}` return true then, if either one or the other are in the list? Can't I check for more than one string at a time?

Comment: @HBMCS: that is because the *truthiness* of `'Venue'` is true since it is a non-empty string, you write `if ('Venue') or ('Promotor' in roleList %}` after all, you should write it as `{% if 'Venue' in roleList or 'Promotor' in roleList %}`.

Comment: This works: (i.e. returns false)  `{% if "Venue" in roleList or "Promoter" in roleList %}` although it doesn't seem very DRY to me.

Comment: Ah, OK, so if I'm checking for ten roles I need to repeat in roleList each time. OK, I'll do that.

Comment: @HBMCS: Django has a permissions framework that is probaby better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django it makes use of `Groups`, so perhaps you can use the permissions framework over writing your own.

Comment: This is checking the properties of Profiles for displaying it to anonymous users, otherwise it'd have been too easy :) . Like, 'do not display the instruments played tab in the profile page of a composer' sort of thing.

Comment: ...or maybe you mean that 'Groups' should be my 'Roles'?

Comment: @HBMCS: well groups are not the permissions, but a group can have zero, one or more permissions. So yes, you can for example use groups over defining a `Role` model I think. Django's admin pages also normally have pages to edit the permissions. Furthemore there are decorators for permission checks.